# How to validate dates are in the format of YYYYMMDD

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a date column having thousands of rows in the format of YYYYMMDD. I have to validate that all the rows are in the correct date format. If there is any row off from the desired format or in any means (say null) the row should be returned in the result. I have the following sample data:

```
  Date           value
 20180101         1
 20180102         2
 20180203         3
 Nan              4
 20180809         5
 08092029         7
 2018-05-06       8
```

Since NAN and 2018-05-06 are not in the desired date format, I want return of these rows. I am aware that *ISDATE()* is available in SQL server, but it gives true value when the date is in any format.

Comment: What data type is that "Date" column? I have a feeling it's not a `date` data type.

Comment: Obligatory comment: If you have any control over the structure of the table, it would be best to change that `(N)(VAR)CHAR` column to a `DATE`, or a `DATETIME`, or a `DATETIME2` data type, so that you don't have to go through this exercise again after some more bad data has been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little tricky.  But I think this does what you want:

```
(case when date like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' and
           try_cast(date, date) is not null
      then 'Valid'
      else 'Yuck!'
 end)
```

SQL Server treats a string of 8 digits as a date in the format as YYYYMMDD as a date, regardless of other settings.  So the above should do exactly what you want.

Comment: I am going to accept your answer as I used like statement to validate my data. Though whole block of code was not working.

Comment: I think try_cast is available from SQL Server 2016 onwards

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if try_cast is available in SQL Server 2012, you can use ISDATE and the len function for this:

```
;with tableA as
(select '20180101' as date1 union
select 'Nan' as date1 union
select '08092029' as date1 union
select '2018-05-06' as date1)

select x.*,
      case when ISDATE(date1)=1 and len(date1)=8 then 'Y'
      else 'N' end as Valid_Flag
 from tableA x
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This would help if there were few rows, however, there are thousands of rows. I just simply put some rows as a sample data here.